# Getting an Apple WatchKit App to pre-compose an SMS message with a line break (with Swift)?

Tags: swift, sms, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm having a little trouble getting my WatchKit App to pre-compose an SMS message with a line break (via the Apple Watch message app).

My current code:

```
let myMessage = "Hi!\nIt's%20me!"

let extent = WKExtension.sharedExtension()
extent.openSystemURL(NSURL(string: "sms:&body=\(myMessage)")!)
```

This code crashes the Watch App but if I take out the "\n" and replace it with "%20"  keeping everything on the same, the function works fine.

Does anyone know how I pre-compose an SMS message like this with a line break?

Comment: Try `%0A` instead of `%20`.

Comment: @Adam Perfect! Thank you